# Как узнать, откуда был инициирован callback?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, отладка

Есть функция, использующая внутри вызов с асинхронным callback (`$.ajax` или просто `window.setTimeout`):

```js
function someFuncton() {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    debugger;
  });
}

function a() {
  someFuncton();
}

function b() {
  someFuncton();
}

b();
```

В отладчике хрома при этом callstack выглядит как

```
(anonymous function) (js:15)
```

Как, при остановке отладчиком на строчке `debugger;`, узнать, откуда был инициирован callback - из `a()` или из `b()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В стеке вызовов, предварительно установив галочку "Async" - асинхронные вызовы захватываются только когда установлена:

[image: Стек вызовов с анонимными вызовами]